# i am having trouble in laravel to get created_at time by while fetching unique data with duplicate count

Tags: laravel

I am having trouble in laravel to get created_at time by following code. When i put created_at in below query - it show all rows instead of unique ips.

```
**Table**
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('visitors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('ip');
        $table->string('url');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('state');
        $table->string('country');
        $table->string('browser')->nullable();
        $table->string('device')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });


**Controller**
    public function show()
    {
        $data = Visitor::select('ip','url','city')->distinct('ip')->get();
        return view('admin.visitors.index', compact('data'));
    }
    

**Blade**
    @foreach($data as $data)
        <tr>
           <td>{{ $i++}}</td>
           <td class="col-md-3">{{ $data->ip }} </td>
           <td class="col-md-3">{{ $data->count() }} </td>
           <td class="col-md-3">{{ $data->url }} </td>
           <td class="col-md-3">{{ $data->city }} </td>
           <td class="col-md-3">{{ $data->state }} </td>
           <td class="col-md-3">{{ $data->created_at->format('d M Y') }} </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: use this query $data = Visitor::all()->unique('ip');

Comment: it gives the unique ip but count give all row count instead of unique ip count.

Answer (score 2):

You've used :

```
    @foreach($data as $data)
```

whereas you should use :

```
@foreach($data as $datum)
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $i++}}</td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $datum->ip }} </td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $datum->count() }} </td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $datum->url }} </td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $datum->city }} </td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $datum->state }} </td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $datum->created_at->format('d M Y') }} </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hello Partner, it gives me the unique ip which is fine but does not provide unique ip's duplicate count. It show all row's count. if you see my query above somehow i was getting unique and their duplicate count as well. But cant get their created at!!

Comment: Your controller isn't asking it to get the duplicate count. You're basically saying "give me each row which has a distinct IP" therefore the count of each will be 1. Easiest option would be to have a separate query which counts the number of times each IP address appears in the table, then pass that data as an array (eg: $counts = array('X.X.X.X' => 10, 'X.X.Y.Y' => 4) and in the third column of your table use {{ $counts[$datum->ip] }} to retrieve that information.